# How do I access night 9 on FNAF 4 on a tablet?

Tags: five-nights-at-freddys-4

How do you access night 9 in FNAF 4 on a tablet? We have searched on youtube. We were able to access all other nights but there does not seem to be a way to start night 9.

Answer (score 1):

I know I'm late, but night 9 is a glitch, you shouldn't worry about it. It involves hacking the game.